# limit function doesn't display the required output in accordance with group by command or distinct command

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I believe this might be quiet one of the familiar questions asked on StackOverflow.

The issue I am facing here is that I am unable to understand why the limit function is not giving me the desired output. From the given table.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXcwp.png)

I want to extract the second highest amount from the given table.

The answer should display as `200`

I had applied  the given query :

```
select distinct amt from amount  order by 1 desc limit 2,1;

 select  amt from amount group by 1 order by 1 desc limit 2,1 ;
```

Could someone help me understand why the limit function is not throwing me the response as per the summarized table instead it's displaying the result as per the base table? also, a query that would give me the desired result.

Comment: could you please post the 'amount table' ?

Comment: Offset starts from 0 not 1.

Comment: @VivekKhandelwal The hyperlink named 'Table' holds the visual form of the table.

Comment: @Mohammed Taher Pansari did you amend your query in line with my comment?

Comment: @P.Salmon Oh ok got your point, yes I got it the query was not throwing the actual result because I was presuming the indexing/offset starts from 1 instead of 0. Many Thanks!